# name of subquery not accessible by where clause

Tags: oracle-11g

```
SELECT
  NAME,
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MOVIERENTED WHERE MOVIERENTED.MOVIEID=MOVIE.MOVIEID) AS RENTCOUNT
FROM MOVIE
ORDER BY RENTCOUNT;
```

Some movies in this database have never been rented, how can I select only the movies that have been rented outside of the subquery?

I have tried adding `WHERE RENTCOUNT > 0` after the `FROM MOVIE` statement.

> ORA-00904: "RENTCOUNT": invalid identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simiply use an Inner Join (your current query using a Scalar Subquery is similar to an Outer Join):

```
SELECT
  MOVIE.NAME,
  COUNT(*) AS RENTCOUNT
FROM MOVIE 
JOIN MOVIERENTED 
ON MOVIERENTED.MOVIEID=MOVIE.MOVIEID
GROUP BY MOVIE.NAME, MOVIE.MOVIEID
ORDER BY RENTCOUNT;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to add a level of nesting

```
select *
  from (SELECT NAME,
               (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                  FROM MOVIERENTED 
                 WHERE MOVIERENTED.MOVIEID=MOVIE.MOVIEID) AS RENTCOUNT
          FROM MOVIE) optional_alias
 where rentcount > 0
 ORDER BY RENTCOUNT;
```